# Android force closes util after screen capture

Tags: android, android-logcat

do anyone know how to read logs? Well I have my logs using adb logcat but I don't know how to trace which cause the program to force close. Well the problem happened to my phone when I use screen capture. My phone model is LG Optimus Black. Here's my log:

```
0
D/LGESensors( 1721): ======   ACCELERATION on 0
D/LGESensors( 1721): skykrkrk _sensorEnable SENSORS_ACCELERATION on aa(0)
D/LGESensors( 1721): skykrkrk control__wake
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): triggering block screen
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): threadLoop before usleep(1000000)
I/VibratorService( 1721): vibratorOff
D/GsmDataConnectionTracker( 1798): LGE_Fast_Dormancy) screen off when current PD
Pstate=(INACTIVE) and DataTransfer=false
D/ActivityManager( 1721): ACTION_SCREEN_OFF received
D/ActivityManager( 1721): There are 44 processes in LRU list
D/ActivityManager( 1721): Free: 194 MB
D/ActivityManager( 1721): Threshold: 100 MB
D/ActivityManager( 1721): There is enough memory!
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): DisplayEventThread About to give-up screen, flinger = 0
x140a48
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): DisplayHardwareBase::releaseScreen() screen given-up
D/WAKEUP_LOG( 1721): Triggering ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP by pid = 1721
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): stuckOnLockScreenBecauseSimMissing()
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): createLockScreen()
V/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): Creation orientation = 1
E/Lockscreen( 1721): LED ON
I/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): Sim state is READY
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): updateLayout: status=Normal
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): >> refreshMusicPlayerDisplay() ----------------------

D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721):    music play info = null
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721):    has music play info = false
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721):    has music play status = started
E/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): mWasMusicActive =  false      mIsMusicActive =  false
        hasMusicPlayInfo =  false    mResume =  false
E/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): [BTUI] ### LockScreen : isOpen(true)
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): maybeEnableFallback()
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): start()
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): next()
D/Andy_DigitalClock( 1721): updateTime(), time = 7:12
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): onScreenTurnedOn()
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): doesFallbackUnlockScreenExist()
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): isVerifyUnlockOnly()
D/StatusBar( 1721): DISABLE_EXPAND: yes
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): refreshEventDisplay()
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): onRefreshMusicPlayerInfo()
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721):     ### music artist = null
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721):     ### music track = null
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721):     ### music state = stop
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): refreshEventDisplay() flag = false
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): refreshEventDisplay() mPluggedIn = true
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): mStatus.showStatusLines() = true, mCharging = Chargin
g (67%), mNextAlarm = null, mBatteryGroup.getVisibility() = 0
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): createSurface for pid 1721 (480 x 762) name=Keyguard
D/Gmail   ( 1859): packageItemInfo:2Google App Engine
D/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): mStatus.showStatusLines() = true, mCharging = Chargin
g (67%), mNextAlarm = Thu 4:45 am, mBatteryGroup.getVisibility() = 0
D/Gmail   ( 1859): packageItemInfo:2Google Finance
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): doesFallbackUnlockScreenExist()
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): isVerifyUnlockOnly()
D/Gmail   ( 1859): packageItemInfo:2Google Voice
D/Gmail   ( 1859): packageItemInfo:2Google Maps
D/Gmail   ( 1859): packageItemInfo:2Google Notebook
D/GoogleLoginService( 1859): onBind: Intent { act=android.accounts.AccountAuthen
ticator cmp=com.google.android.gsf/.loginservice.GoogleLoginService }
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): run()
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): next()
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): showAlmostAtAccountLoginDialog()
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY
_CHANGED
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): handleBatteryUpdate
D/dalvikvm( 2050): GC_EXPLICIT freed 841 objects / 40672 bytes in 75ms
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): showAlmostAtAccountLoginDialog()
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): received broadcast android.intent.action.TIME_TI
CK
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): handleTimeUpdate
D/StatusBarPolicy( 1721): updateClock(), time = 7:13 PM
D/Andy_DigitalClock( 1721): updateTime(), time = 7:13
D/Andy_DigitalClock( 1721): updateTime(), time = 7:13
D/skia    ( 1721): purging 188K from font cache [17 entries]
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): showAlmostAtAccountLoginDialog()
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY
_CHANGED
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): handleBatteryUpdate
D/dalvikvm( 2165): GC_EXPLICIT freed 309 objects / 14760 bytes in 72ms
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): showAlmostAtAccountLoginDialog()
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY
_CHANGED
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): handleBatteryUpdate
D/dalvikvm( 2243): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1024 objects / 41792 bytes in 194ms
D/dalvikvm( 1859): GC_EXPLICIT freed 1705 objects / 92728 bytes in 80ms
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): showAlmostAtAccountLoginDialog()
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY
_CHANGED
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): handleBatteryUpdate
D/dalvikvm( 2515): GC_EXPLICIT freed 46 objects / 2232 bytes in 185ms
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1721): wakeWhenReadyLocked(26)
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1721): handleWakeWhenReady(26)
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): wakeWhenReadyTq()
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1721): pokeWakelock(5000)
I/power   ( 1721): *** set_screen_state 1
D/LGESensors( 1721): skykrkrk control__activate handle=acceleration (0) enabled=
1
D/LGESensors( 1721): ======   ACCELERATION on 1
D/LGESensors( 1721): skykrkrk _sensorEnable SENSORS_ACCELERATION on aa(1)
D/LGESensors( 1721): skykrkrk control__set_delay: dev=0x336ee8 delay-ms=200 hSen
sor=0
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): onScreenTurnedOn()
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): doesFallbackUnlockScreenExist()
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): isVerifyUnlockOnly()
I/touchCheck( 1721): WMS's KEY event : KeyEvent{action=1 code=26 repeat=0 meta=0
 scancode=116 chars=null mFlags=8}
I/touchCheck( 1721): ViewRoot's Key event KeyEvent{action=1 code=26 repeat=0 met
a=0 scancode=116 chars=null mFlags=8}
D/StatusBarPolicy( 1721): updateClock(), time = 7:13 PM
D/Andy_DigitalClock( 1721): updateTime(), time = 7:13
D/GsmDataConnectionTracker( 1798): [GsmDataConnectionTracker] onDataStateChanged
(): 0 data calls received
D/Andy_DigitalClock( 1721): updateTime(), time = 7:13
I/PowerManagerService( 1721): stepLocked animation finished mask:2 curIntValue:1
06
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): DisplayEventThread Screen about to return, flinger = 0x
140a48
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): DisplayHardwarebase::acquireScreen() screen returned
I/touchCheck( 1721): MeNano's ACTION_DOWN - x : 62.88031, y : 308.87268
I/touchCheck( 1721): WMS's ACTION_DOWN - x : 62.88031, y : 308.87268
I/touchCheck( 1721): ViewRoot's Touch Event : MotionEvent{46d4c020 action=0 x=62
.88031 y=270.87268
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1721): pokeWakelock(2000)
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1721): pokeWakelock(2000)
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1721): pokeWakelock(7000)
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1721): pokeWakelock(7000)
D/KeyguardViewMediator( 1721): pokeWakelock(7000)
I/touchCheck( 1721): MeNano's ACTION_UP - x : 0.0, y : 684.32874
I/touchCheck( 1721): WMS's ACTION_UP - x : 0.0, y : 684.32874
I/touchCheck( 1721): ViewRoot's Touch Event : MotionEvent{46d4c398 action=1 x=0.
0 y=646.32874
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): reportSuccessfulUnlockAttempt()
I/OSP     ( 1721): rotationForOrientationLw::useSensor::curRotation=0, lastRotat
ion=0
I/#LGIME  ( 1792): ### onFinishInput
I/#LGIME  ( 1792): #### onStartInput restarting : false / inputType : 0
W/InputManagerService( 1721): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: co
m.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@46c06c50
V/Orientation( 1721): tiltFlag Changed -> false
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): removeLayer_l     name=Keyguard
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): cleanUp()
I/Lockscreen( 1721): onPause isScreenOn true
D/GestureSensorManager( 1721): unRegisterSensor()
E/Andy_LockScreen2( 1721): [BTUI] ### LockScreen : isOpen(false)
E/LockPatternKeyguardView( 1721): showAlmostAtAccountLoginDialog()
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): received broadcast android.intent.action.BATTERY
_CHANGED
D/KeyguardUpdateMonitor( 1721): handleBatteryUpdate
D/WindowManager( 1721): intercept key tq Keydocd code= 3will be mReject clear
I/VibratorService( 1721): vibratorOff
I/touchCheck( 1721): WMS's KEY event : KeyEvent{action=0 code=3 repeat=0 meta=0
scancode=102 chars=null mFlags=8}
I/ActivityManager( 1721): Starting activity: Intent { flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.lge
.util/.ScreencaptureActivity }
I/ActivityManager( 1721): process name to start: android.process.acore
D/VibratorService( 1721): [DK] vibratorOn()... milliseconds = 10,  mVibrateVolum
e = -1
I/VibratorService( 1721): vibratorOn() vibrate_level = 5, timeout_ms = 10
I/ActivityManager( 1721): Start proc android.process.acore for activity com.lge.
util/.ScreencaptureActivity: pid=3109 uid=10036 gids={1015, 3003}
D/VibratorService( 1721): [DK] vibratorOn()... milliseconds = 30,  mVibrateVolum
e = -1
I/VibratorService( 1721): vibratorOn() vibrate_level = 5, timeout_ms = 30
D/skia    ( 3109): SHAPER: changerequest 1 -> 5
V/MediaPlayerJAVA( 3109): Call MediaPlayer create!
V/MediaPlayerJAVA( 3109): Call MediaPlayer Create! Context:com.lge.util.Screenca
ptureActivity@468d48c0 file: com.lge.util:raw/sc_sound
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): Client(11) constructor
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): Create new client(11) from pid 3109, fd=41, offset=
871012, length=25644 Start
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): [11] setDataSource fd=41, offset=871012, length=256
44
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): getPlayerType ident == 1179011410 46464952 ident&0x
0000F6FF=[4052]
E/MediaPlayerService( 1628): The Default Player is PV_PLAYER********************
***
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): player type = 1
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628):  create PVPlayer
I/touchCheck( 1721): WMS's KEY event : KeyEvent{action=1 code=3 repeat=0 meta=0
scancode=102 chars=null mFlags=8}
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): Create new client(11) from pid 3109, fd=41, offset=
871012, length=25644 END
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): [11] setAudioStreamType(3)
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): [11] prepareAsync
D/ITTIAM_AVIPPLUGIN( 1628): This is Not an AVI file
D/PVPlayerEngine( 1628): ACESONG :      PVP_ENGINE_COMMAND_PREPARE 1
D/PVPlayerEngine( 1628): ACESONG : PVP_ENGINE_STATE_TRACK_SELECTION_1_DONE 1
E/PV_COMPONENT( 1628): MyTrackSelectionHelper::SelectTracks() inital list:
D/PV_COMPONENT( 1628): ~~~~~FileFormat X-WAV-FF
D/PVPlayerEngine( 1628): ACESONG : PVP_ENGINE_STATE_TRACK_SELECTION_2_DONE 1
D/PVPlayerEngine( 1628): ACESONG : PVP_ENGINE_STATE_TRACK_SELECTION_3_DONE 1
V/AudioSink( 1628): open(32000, 1, 1, 4)
D/AudioSystem( 1628): [HARDLINE] setStreamtype in AudioSystem =3
D/AudioHardwareALSA( 1628): [HARDLINE] streamType =3
V/AudioSink( 1628): setVolume
D/audiothread( 1628): Set Audio Sink on ActiveTiming
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): [11] notify (0xbd2a8, 200, 1, 44)
W/MediaPlayer( 3109): info/warning (1, 44)
D/MediaPlayer( 3109): frameworks/base/media/libmedia/mediaplayer.cpp::notify Div
X Media Info
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): [11] notify (0xbd2a8, 1, 0, 0)
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): [11] setLooping(0)
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): [11] setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
V/AudioSink( 1628): setVolume(1.000000, 1.000000)
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): [11] start
V/AudioSink( 1628): flush
V/AudioSink( 1628): start
D/AudioPolicyManagerALSA( 1628): getDeviceForStrategy() device2 0
D/AudioPolicyManagerALSA( 1628): computeVolume()...volume = 0.100000 , stream(3)

V/AudioSink( 1628): SOLE_STST :: + setAudioEffect() MUST be called before this l
og.-----#2 iEnableAudioEffect:-1
I/        ( 3071):  writescreencaptureData socket: 9
D/MediaPlayerJAVA( 3109): Info (1,44)
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): createSurface for pid 3109 (1 x 1) name=com.lge.util/co
m.lge.util.ScreencaptureActivity
I/#LGIME  ( 1792): #### onStartInput restarting : false / inputType : 0
D/Omap3ALSA( 1628): [s_route] devices 00000002 in mode 0 handle=0 handle->device
s=0000878f handle->curDev=00000002
D/Omap3ALSA( 1628): [s_route] samplerate=44100, channel=2, buffersize=4128 mode=
0
D/Omap3ALSA( 1628): [s_open] devName=default
D/ALSAControl( 1628): [LUCKYJUN77] getVoIPCallState : 0
D/ALSAControl( 1628): [LUCKYJUN77] setMasterVolume
I/Omap3ALSA( 1628): [s_open] Initialized ALSA PLAYBACK, device default, err = 0
I/ActivityManager( 1721): Displayed activity com.lge.util/.ScreencaptureActivity
: 222 ms (total 222 ms)
D/dalvikvm( 3109): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 903 objects / 63904 bytes in 27ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 3109): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.464MB for 1536016-byte alloca
tion
V/AudioSink( 1628): stop
D/dalvikvm( 3109): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 77 objects / 4104 bytes in 41ms
I/ScreencaptureServer( 3109): getData length=1536000
I/        ( 3118):  Screencaptured Accept lsocket: 12
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): [11] notify (0xbd2a8, 2, 0, 0)
D/dalvikvm( 3109): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 90 objects / 4000 bytes in 39ms
I/dalvikvm-heap( 3109): Grow heap (frag case) to 5.929MB for 1536016-byte alloca
tion
D/dalvikvm( 3109): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 167 objects / 7648 bytes in 63ms
D/dalvikvm( 3109): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 12 objects / 384 bytes in 48ms
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): [11] stop
V/AudioSink( 1628): stop
V/AudioSink( 1628): stop
V/AudioSink( 1628): stop
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): disconnect(11) from pid 3109
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): Client(11) destructor pid = 3109
V/AudioSink( 1628): close
V/MediaPlayerService( 1628): disconnect(11) from pid 3109
V/MediaPlayerJAVA( 3109): MediaPlayer release!
W/dalvikvm( 3109): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
0020c20)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside
 thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)

E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at com.lge.util.ScreencaptureActivity.saveCapute
dImage(ScreencaptureActivity.java:397)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at com.lge.util.ScreencaptureActivity.access$600
(ScreencaptureActivity.java:56)
E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at com.lge.util.ScreencaptureActivity$2.run(Scre
encaptureActivity.java:144)
W/ActivityManager( 1721):   Force finishing activity com.lge.util/.Screencapture
Activity
D/skia    ( 1721): SHAPER: changerequest 1 -> 5
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): createSurface for pid 1721 (1 x 1) name=Sorry!
W/ActivityManager( 1721): Duplicate finish request for HistoryRecord{46bac040 co
m.lge.util/.ScreencaptureActivity}
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): removeLayer_l     name=com.lge.util/com.lge.util.Screen
captureActivity
E/AudioHardwareALSA( 1628): CALLING STANDBY
D/AudioHardwareALSA( 1628): Veena In AudioStreamOutAlsa Standby1
D/Omap3ALSA( 1628): [s_route] devices ffffffff in mode 0 handle=712480 handle->d
evices=0000878f handle->curDev=00000002
D/Omap3ALSA( 1628): [s_route] samplerate=44100, channel=2, buffersize=4128 mode=
0
D/Omap3ALSA( 1628): [s_route]devices == -1!!!!
I/touchCheck( 1721): MeNano's ACTION_DOWN - x : 267.2413, y : 532.2043
I/touchCheck( 1721): WMS's ACTION_DOWN - x : 267.2413, y : 532.2043
I/touchCheck( 1721): ViewRoot's Touch Event : MotionEvent{46d4c398 action=0 x=26
7.2413 y=305.20428
I/touchCheck( 1721): MeNano's ACTION_UP - x : 260.30597, y : 545.61346
I/touchCheck( 1721): WMS's ACTION_UP - x : 260.30597, y : 545.61346
I/touchCheck( 1721): ViewRoot's Touch Event : MotionEvent{46d4c020 action=1 x=26
0.30597 y=318.61346
I/Process ( 3109): Sending signal. PID: 3109 SIG: 9
I/#LGIME  ( 1792): #### onStartInput restarting : false / inputType : 0
I/ActivityManager( 1721): Process android.process.acore (pid 3109) has died.
D/SurfaceFlinger( 1721): removeLayer_l     name=Sorry!
D/StatusBarPolicy( 1721): onSignalStrengthsChanged called. mSignalStrength : Sig
nalStrength: 21 99 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 gsm
D/StatusBarPolicy( 1721): updateSignalStrength() Called. mPhoneData.icondID=1730
2306
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception logs in your application are following:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-8
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3109): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside
     thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)

    E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:258)

    E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at com.lge.util.ScreencaptureActivity.saveCapute
    dImage(ScreencaptureActivity.java:397)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at com.lge.util.ScreencaptureActivity.access$600
    (ScreencaptureActivity.java:56)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3109):        at com.lge.util.ScreencaptureActivity$2.run(Scre
    encaptureActivity.java:144)
```

and it is because, you are calling Toast.makeText(,,,).show() inside method ScreenCaptureAcitvity in method saveCapturedImage(), which is in another thread than UI/Event thread. Use Handler in case you want to notify Event thread from another thread.

Comment: So it was caused by one of my widget am I right? and by the way, I don't code it or whatever it just happened to appear in my phone while I'm testing it. I just wonder which app cause this problem.

Comment: I dont know which widget it is, but by logs we can see it has package com.lge.util package and activity anme ScreenCaptureActivity.java. You can see logs specific to your application in ddms mode, in process selection by selection of your application package.